# Not run the BroadcastReceiver codes

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have the numbers in the database.

I want to list incoming SMS messages if this number was equal to.

My problem is that my final part of codes is not running. (After the end If).

Please guide me.thanks

incomingSms :

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

            SmsMessage currentmessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
            String phoneNumber = currentmessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

            String senderNum = phoneNumber;
            String message = currentmessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

            Log.i("payam", "senderNum=" + senderNum + " | msg=" + message);
            DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(context);
            db.open();
            List<sh_number> blocknumbers = db.getAllNUMBERItem();
            db.close();
            for (sh_number thisblocknumber : blocknumbers) {
                if (senderNum.equals(thisblocknumber.getnumber())) {

                    Toast.makeText(context, "پیام دریافتی بلاک شد. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    sh_msg thisMsg = new sh_msg();
                    thisMsg.setText(message);
                    thisMsg.setnumber(senderNum);
                    db.open();
                    db.insertSH_MSG(thisMsg);
                    db.close();
                    abortBroadcast();


                }
          /*if(senderNum.equals("5554")){
                Toast.makeText(context, "پیام دریافتی بلاک شد. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                sh_msg thisMsg = new sh_msg();
                thisMsg.setText(message);
                thisMsg.setnumber(senderNum);
                db.open();
                db.insertSH_MSG(thisMsg);
                db.close();
                abortBroadcast();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum="+senderNum+" | msg="+message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }*/

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.anything

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the receiver class in your manifest file,if you don't add this code your receiver class is not working!!   please check that one.

```
<receiver
        android:name=".IncomingSms"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Yes